# Can an em-dash function as both an opener to its own parenthetical and simultaneously close a nonrestrictive clause introduced by a comma?

Tags: em-dashes, parentheticals, non-restrictive, parenthetical-commas

I've read that you are not supposed to include a comma before 'in which', since it is part of a restrictive clause linked to a noun. If you do put a comma before it, it is to render it part of a nonrestrictive parenthetical, but you  might misdirect what the 'in which' modifies. In the following sentence, however, (sorry it's a bit long) I'm confused about the roles of 'in which', the comma, and an em-dash that both closes the first parenthetical while simultaneously opening a new one.

> Its purpose is to turn the scattered stains of life, in which we can hardly be recognized—by eliminating those in which we no longer see ourselves, and by choosing from what remains those most recognizable and thus closest to the current form of our personality—first into a clearly profiled silhouette, and then into a pure form that is harmonious with our own present conception of ourselves.”

If the long em-dash parenthetical is removed, the complete sentence reads: "Its purpose is to turn the scattered stains of life, in which we can hardly be recognized first into a clearly profiled silhouette..."

In that case, you have to add a comma after 'recognized' even if you want to remove the first comma to make it restrictive. But when the em-dash is present it acts like that second comma, both closing one parenthetical and then opening another. Is that possible?

Thank you

Comment: Yes. The rule 'what is left after removal of a parenthetical must be grammatical, correctly punctuated, and have the same sense as the whole sentence' is not quite absolute. Thus 'He is an (otherwise) charming man.' is correct. Here, the dash will do dual purpose (though the use of long multiple parentheticals in a sentence, especially sequentially, is itself iffy. Rephrasing may well add clarity.)

Comment: Great, thank you!

Comment: The cited text is stylistically so bad I can't even be bothered to check it for syntactic validity. You should devote more attention to learning what's acceptable in *actual spoken English* before looking at the vagaries of orthographic punctuation.

Comment: I recognize how convoluted the section sounds. It is taken so out of context, it's logic is almost impossible to follow. The author has already developed the meaning of what here seem like totally abstract terms, like stains into a silhouette by some form of selection.  Saying I need to go learn spoken English is not an observation that seems to be made in very good spirits for such a learned forum as this. What I posted is part of an ongoing process of editing someone's translation of a notoriously difficult (but incredible) writer, who frequently uses long parentheticals.

Comment: If you know something is bad English, don't come here asking "Is this bad English?"

Comment: Clearly I didn't come here asking that. Edwin answered the question I did in fact ask, commented rationally and respectfully about rephrasing, and ended all necessity for further comments. Then you two show up with douchey bro attitudes like it's a personal attack. You have no purpose here.